# Error in IAM custom policy to restrict a user on the basis of tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, policy, amazon-iam

I have created a `custom IAM policy` to restrict a user access on the basis of tags like if the `Resource tag Name` has any value Test then the user can `start stop reboot` the instance.

Here is my policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["ec2:Describe*"],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissionsWithTags",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:acct_no:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "Test"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I apply the policy the user can't perform the specified actions.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ForAnyValue` is an inappropriate [condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition) for your [Amazon IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) use case, insofar it is only applicable for sets (see [Creating a Condition That Tests Multiple Key Values (Set Operations)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/conditions-setoperators.html) for details) - simply dropping the `ForAnyValue:` prefix should yield a working policy, see e.g. the examples in [Resource-level Permissions for EC2 – Controlling Management Access on Specific Instances](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx29HCT3ABL7LP3/Resource-level-Permissions-for-EC2-Controlling-Management-Access-on-Specific-Ins):

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",      
        "ec2:RebootInstances",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/critical":"true"
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:your_region:your_account_ID:instance/*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: here `critical` means a `tag` whose value is `true`?